# How to calculate groupwise proportion (within group propotion) for categorical columns using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, proportions

I have found a one line solution that works well.

**Here, the goal is to estimate the location-wise gender proportion for a research study.**

```
# Data Frame
df = pd.DataFrame({"location": {0: "site 1", 1: "site 1", 2: "site 2", 3: "site 2", 4: "site 1"},
                   "gender": {0: "male", 1: "female", 2: "male", 3: "female", 4: "female"}})

print(df)
```

[image: Data Frame]

Used following steps to produce the result

Step 1. apply groupby

Step 2. use value_count

Step 3. use unstack

Step 4. multiply with 100 and put everything inside a round function.

```
round(df.groupby(['location'])['gender'].value_counts(normalize = True).unstack()*100, 2)
```

[image: Proportion Table]

***Are there any other solutions? If anyone has an alternative solution/code, please share it here.***

Comment: Can you update your post with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: Now, I have added a context with code examples.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good solution.

Maybe you can replace `round(..., 2)` by `.round(2)` and fill `NaN` by 0.

```
>>> df.groupby('location')['gender'] \
      .value_counts(normalize=True) \
      .unstack() \
      .mul(100) \
      .round(2) \
      .fillna(0)

# Output
gender    female   male
location
site 1     66.67  33.33
site 2     50.00  50.00
```

**OR**

You can use `pd.crosstab` to do without `groupby`:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df['location'], df['gender']) \
      .apply(lambda x: round(x / x.sum() * 100, 2), axis=1)

# Output
gender    female   male
location
site 1     66.67  33.33
site 2     50.00  50.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got another solution, but this uses *R's dplyr style code* in python. To implement this, I used python's ***dfply*** library.

```
# Import libraries
from dfply import *
import pandas as pd

# Data Frame
df = pd.DataFrame({"location": {0: "site 1", 1: "site 1", 2: "site 2", 3: "site 2", 4: "site 1"},
               "gender": {0: "male", 1: "female", 2: "male", 3: "female", 4: "female"}})


# dfply code

(
df >>
select(X.location, X.gender) >>
group_by(X.location, X.gender) >>
summarize(Count = n(X.gender)) >>
    group_by(X.location) >>
    mutate(Proportion = (X.Count/(X.Count).sum()).mul(100))
).round(2)
```

Here is the result

[image: dfply implementation output]

Comment: I don't understand why you prefer a more complex solution? and it's not the same output you expect???

Comment: Actually, I was looking for alternative solutions, not just the optimized one. Basically,  wanted to know different ways one can achieve the same output in Python.